# How to remove a section of a CubeGeometry?

Tags: three.js, physics, csg

At the moment I'm using ThreeCSG/CSG to subtract a small cube from a much larger cube. This works fine, but only the look of it changes not the actual geometry. So when using PhysiJS (Physics engine) on another cube, it doesn't fall into the hole but acts like it normally would. [Click for Demo](http://gamingspire.com/game/test2.php).

Is there any way I can actually remove a section from a CubeGeometry so that objects can fall into it - not just for display purposes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThreeCSG does change the geometry, by which I mean geometry in the sense of Three.js -- the collection of vertices, the faces, etc.  I think what you mean is that ThreeCSG does not change the *physics-based properties* of your object.

According to https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Basic-Shapes , it appears as though you have to use `Physijs.ConcaveMesh` as it "matches any concave geometry you have, i.e. arbitrary mesh", and it is the only one that has a change of supporting a non-convex physical object.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I've changed the floor-cube to a Physijs.ConcaveMesh and the falling cube now falls/glitches through the hole. Would you be able to take a look? :) I've created another cube next to it to show that the physics work on the original cube still. http://gamingspire.com/game/test2.php

Comment: Your example looks good -- what do you mean by "glitching" through the hole? And if my response answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: The left cube falls through the hole but doesn't stop falling. Like, doesn't sit inside the hole. You might need to move the camera to see what I mean :)

Comment: How about if you store the last known collision-free position, and when a collision is detected, in addition to setting the velocity to zero, also reset the position to the last known collision-free position?